# summation of binomial series

Tags: summation

Can someone pls provide the approach/solution to this problem
$$\sum_{r=1}^n \begin{pmatrix}n\\r\end{pmatrix}\sin(rx) \cos((n-r)x)$$
I have tried to simplify the sine and cosine terms and then arrived at this part but am unable to solve any further...
$$\sum_{r=1}^n \begin{pmatrix}n\\r\end{pmatrix}\frac {\sin(2rx-nx)}{2}+2^{n-1} \sin(nx)-\frac{\sin(nx)}{2}$$
Also it would be very helpful if you can advice on how to approach such questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For answering the question first observe the fact that $\displaystyle \binom{n}{k} = \binom{n}{n-k}$

let $$\begin{align} S &= \sum_{r =\color{red}0}^{n}\binom{n}{r}\sin(rx)\cos((n-r)x)\\
S&=\sum_{r =\color{red}0}^{n}\binom{n}{n-r}\sin((n-r)x)\cos(rx) = \sum_{r=1}^{n}\binom{n}{n-r}\sin((n-r)x)\cos(rx) + \sin(0x)\cos(nx) \\
2S &= \sum_{r =\color{red}0}^{n}\binom{n}{r}\sin(rx + (n-r)x)\\
2S &= \sin(nx)\sum_{r = 0}^{n}\binom{n}{r}  \end{align}$$

Or $$\boxed{S = 2^{n-1}\sin(nx)} $$

Comment: An addition to your answer is that $r = 0$ is valid because $\sin(0) = 0$

Comment: Thanks I'll edit my answer

Comment: Hi! I just read the solution but have two doubts...first being that even if sin(0) will make the first term 0 in the first representation bu the second one will remain non zero as cos(0) will become 1...the second one is  that if we consider the property nCr=nCn-r we should only be replacing the binomial coefficient term not the argument of sin and cos itself.

These are just two doubts I had...I don't know whether they are valid or not..pls correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: I am reversing the sum and for $\cos(0)$ it is the $n^{th}$ term

Comment: ok got it thanks